# How to create a package to install all the dependencies python script needs

Tags: python, linux, package-managers

My project consists of a python script(.py file) which has following dependencies :
1) numpy
2) scipy
3) sklearn
4) opencv (cv2)
5) dlib
6) torch
and many more ...

That is , the python script imports all of the above.
In order to run this script I need to manually install all of the dependencies by running 'pip install' or 'sudo apt-get install' commands on bash.

For dependencies like dlib , opencv and torch I need to curl the respective repositories build them using cmake and then install .(Here again i need to apt-get install cmake).

As a result I run a lot of commands just get the setup ready to run one python .py script.

Is there anyway I can build all these dependencies , package them , and just install everything using one command ?

PS :- I am a beginner in python . So please forgive if my question seems silly .

Thanks !!

Manasi

Answer (score 0):

I know that this Response may be a bit late. However, even if you can't benefit from this information now, perhaps someone else who may be looking for a similar answer will stumble onto this posting one day.

You can use [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/) or [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/) Modules, along w/ the [conda](https://pypi.org/project/conda/) Package Manager to Package and Compile an Executable. You will also need to install [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases), if you're working on the Windows Platform.

If your project includes Non-Python Dependencies, you may also want to take a look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System). If you plan on running Python Scripts during the Unpacking/Installation process, the NSIS Website also has [NsPython Plugins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsPython_plug-in) available, for that purpose.

I hope this helps to get you started!

Answer (score -1):

In case of only python dependencies, use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).
In case of others, write a shell script which has all the installation commands.

Comment: I don't want separate environments for separate projects.
I want some way , so that the user can easily install all the dependencies instead of running all the install commands one by one on linux terminal.
The end user might be running the script on another computer (with the same OS)

Comment: Here you provide all dependencies you need in `requirements.txt`. Anyone who wants to install all these dependencies needs to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the virtual environment.

Comment: Libraries like opencv need to be downloaded(git clone from github repository) and build from source using cmake whose end result is a cv2.so file to be saved in python/site-packages

For such situations how to use requirements.txt file ?

Also , the packages that are installed using apt-get install how to mention them in requirements.txt ?

According to my knowledge pip will install only those packages installed on PyPi , is that right ? So how should I install non python packages/libraries

Comment: Okay. Then write a shell script which has all the installation commands.

Comment: That is definitely a last option .
But is there any other way ?

Comment: Not that I know of.